# ASP Function definitions location

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

I am trying to understand some files in my router's firmware and I have many files with lines like those:

```
<% getCfgZero(1, "OperationMode"); %>
<% getCfgGenera(1, "OperationMode"); %>
```

I was trying to grep definitions of those functions but I can not find them. Do you know where it might be stored?

Comment: I doubt your router uses ASP given ASP3.0 only runs on Windows (Chilisoft notwithstanding). This is probably another templating system just with similar syntax.

Comment: @Dai Anyway, do you know where the definitions might be located?

Comment: They're probably built-in to whatever system the firmware is using.

Comment: 1. as @Dai told you, perhaps you are using not Microsoft ASP 3.0.
2. Run VisualStudio and debug your code. Put "STOP" command before "getCfgZero";

Comment: @Zam What are you on about?

Comment: @Lankymart. If i understand correctly he looking where this function definied. One possible way: find it durining debugging.

Comment: @Zam Yes in the firmware of a router, not your classic debugging location.